Ds 160 query about listing maiden name in application
Theres a question on the ds 160 that says "were you known by any other names?(spiritual, maiden, nickenames etc)
I have to renew my wife's b2 visa. I dont remember if i answered this question 10yrs ago since she had a different last name before we got married. She adopted my name as her last name post wedding. So if this question pertains to the last name also then should i answer it? Will she be refused visa for not mentioning this ten yrs ago?

If your wife had a different maiden name, then yes, it's an "other name" and should be listed in the application.
In practice listing or not listing it is unlikely to make any difference unless they think you're intentionally hiding something: for example, if she previously visited the US using her maiden name and overstayed, murdered somebody with an axe, etc.
Update: Since you've stated that she has never visited the US under her maiden name, the US will have no records of that name. You should still include it in the application for completeness, but it's unlikely to be a problem if you don't. The fact that it was not mentioned 10 years in an old visa application is irrelevant.

I forgot to mention it last time we applied. Its just that her last name for different.  First name has always been the same.

@Mohd Did she ever visit the US or have a US visa in her maiden name?  If no, it doesn't really matter.

Nope. Previous visa was under the new name post marriage.
